# How can I extract an attribute from a list of dictionaries?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a list of users already defined in Ansible `group_vars` as shown below:

```yaml
accountnames:
  - {user: foo, userfn: 'Foo Bar'}
  - {user: test, userfn: 'Test Acct1'}
  - {user: blah, userfn: 'Blah Boom'}
```

How can I extract only the usernames and make it a list to add users using [`ipa_group`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ipa_group_module.html#community-general-ipa-group-module-manage-freeipa-group) module without listing all of my users as I have below? (I don't want to create a duplicate list in my *groupvar* with just usernames too)

```yaml
- name: Ensure that users assigned to the group
  ipa_group:
    name: sysops
    user:
      - foo
      - test
      - blah
    ipa_host: ipa.example.com
    ipa_user: admin
    ipa_pass: pass
```

I have tried the following, but it errors out with TypeError:

> unhashable type: 'dict'

```yaml
- name: Ensure that users assigned to the group
  ipa_group:
    name: sysops
    user: "{{ accountnames }}"
    ipa_host: ipa.example.com
    ipa_user: admin
    ipa_pass: pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [*map*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.map) filter

```yaml
    - name: Ensure that users assigned to the group
      ipa_group:
        name: sysops
        user: "{{ accountnames | map(attribute='user') | list }}"
        ipa_host: ipa.example.com
        ipa_user: admin
        ipa_pass: pass
```